# KeyError: Adding and modifying dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project, and I'm having some difficulties with manipulating dictionaries. I have a dictionary representing student information, and I want to perform certain operations on it. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
    student_info = {
        'John': {'age': 20, 'grade': 'A'},
        'Catherine': {'age': 22, 'grade': 'B'},
        'Bob': {'age': 21, 'grade': 'C'}
    }
    
    # Now, I want to update John's age and add a new student, but I'm encountering issues.
    # Here's my attempt:
    student_info['John']['age'] = 21
    student_info['Eva']['age'] = 23  # Trying to add a new student
    print(student_info)
```

The problem is that the attempt to add a new student is giving me a KeyError. I'm not sure how to handle this, and I'm also wondering if there's a more efficient way to update the age of a student.
Could someone please review my code and suggest how I can update the age of a student and add a new student without encountering errors? Additionally, any tips on best practices for dictionary manipulation in Python would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What should Eva's grade be? Why should it make sense to specify her age separately?

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the code is that the 'Eva' key doesn't exist in the student_info dictionary, and because you are trying to access it directly, it results in an error.

To fix this, you should check whether the 'Eva' key exists in your dictionary before trying to access it. If not, you can use the 'get method' to set a default value if the key doesn't exist.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```
student_info['John']['age'] = 21

if 'Eva' in student_info:
    student_info['Eva']['age'] = 23
else:
    student_info['Eva'] = {'age': 23, 'grade': 'A'}

print(student_info)
```

The code checks if 'Eva' is already in the 'student_info' dictionary, and if she is not, the code adds a new entry with her age and grade to the dictionary. This way, you avoid the KeyError. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

For these cases you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

student_info = defaultdict(
    dict,
    {
        "John": {"age": 20, "grade": "A"},
        "Catherine": {"age": 22, "grade": "B"},
        "Bob": {"age": 21, "grade": "C"},
    },
)


student_info["John"]["age"] = 21

# "Eva" doesn't exist, so create new dictionary {"age": 23}:
student_info["Eva"]["age"] = 23

print(student_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `Eva` exists in `student_info` before doing `student_info['Eva']['age'] = 23`

So, you'd need to do the following:

```
  student_info['Eva'] = {'age': 23}
```

Now that 'Eva' exists in `student_info`, you can now do:

```
  student_info['Eva']['grade'] = 'B'
```